# Save bash exit code

Tags: bash, prompt, exit-code

I am trying to create a colourful and somewhat informative bash prompt but I cannot figure out how to save the $? exit code for later use after the if test (which seems to change $?).
Doing:

```
exit_code=$?
PS1="\$(if (( \$? == 0 )); then echo \"$GREEN\"; else echo \"$RED\"; fi)$exit_code $NORMAL\u@\h $BLUE\W`if (( $UID == 0 )); then echo \"$RED#\" else echo \"$GREEN$\"; fi`$NORMAL "
```

does not seem to work either. Both $? and exit_code will be 0 after the test.

I am sure this is possible somehow in bash, but how?

This is my PS1 so far:

```
PS1="\$(if (( \$? == 0 )); then echo \"$GREEN\"; else echo \"$RED\"; fi)$?$NORMAL\u@\h $BLUE\W`if (( $UID == 0 )); then echo \"$RED#\" else echo \"$GREEN$\"; fi`$NORMAL "
```

And $? is just zero even though the colour changes between red and green depending on the exit code, this is what makes me thing that it is the if test that sets it to zero.

I know it would be easier to read if split up on multiple lines but I prefer to keep this as a one liner.

If you see any other errors please also let me know as I am just poking here and there to see what works because I am getting quite confused about where I need to put backslashes and where I don't.

GREEN, BLUE, RED and NORMAL are just colours defined above to make things less cryptic.

Comment: Keep in mind that `(( ... ))` is a command like any other, not syntax, and so sets the value of `$?`. However, the way its written (succeed if `$?` is zero, fail if not) would only have the effect of setting it to zero when it is already zero, and to 1 when it is non-zero, so that doesn't really explain what you are seeing. Also, none of this should have any affect on `exit_code`. Are you sure you don't run any other commands prior to `exit_code=$?` that would reset `$?`?

Answer (score 1):

I build my prompt this way:

```
user_host_path="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot) }"'\u@\h: \w'
xterm_title='\[\e]0;'"$user_host_path"'\a\]'
[[ $TERM == xterm* || $TERM == rxvt* ]] && line1="${xterm_title}"
git_branch='$(git_current_branch)'
line1="${line1}${user_host_path}${git_branch}"
line2='\! \$ '
print_time='printf "%*s" $((COLUMNS - 9)) " "|sed "s/./˙/g"; date "+ %T"'
color_bold='\[\033[0;1m\]'
color_reset='\[\033[0m\]'
PROMPT_COMMAND="_rc_=\$?;${print_time};((_rc_!=0)) && PS1='${line1}\n${color_bold}[\$_rc_]${color_reset} ${line2}' || PS1='${line1}\n${line2}'"
```

So, the key is to save `$?` inside the prompt var.

Comment: Yes but the problem is that I need to use the value of $? after an if test which seems to interfere with its value.

Comment: I do the same thing in my last line. Just save it before you do the test.

Comment: Ah I see. I see what you do but can't get anything useful out of it. I tried PROMPT_COMMAND="_rc_=$?;((_rc_!=0)) && PS1='$RED$_rc_' || PS1='$GREEN$_rc_'" but it shows no number, it only makes the text red or green.

Comment: the code in your comment is not well formatted. Did you do `_rc_=\$?` -- have to protect the variable in a double quoted string.

Comment: PROMPT_COMMAND="_rc_=\$?;((_rc_!=0)) && PS1=\"$RED$_rc_\" || PS1=\"$GREEN$_rc_\"". Same thing. No number. Also I just did a check at the prompt and it I'm pretty sure that when $? changes, _rc_ also changes. Maybe my system is configured incorrectly? EDIT: it seems to delete some _'s, but it's in my bashrc.

Comment: Check the "help" link for comments. Underscores are formatting for italics.  Use backticks to format code snippets.

Comment: Isn't there an easier way to save $? or is it strictly necessary to it like this?

Comment: You have to save the value in a variable. you can use whatever variable name you choose.

Comment: As shown in the first example, I did save it in a variable, but the variable changes value when $? does.